# Formula to project a vector onto a plane in the direction of another vector

Tags: python, math, 3d, linear-algebra, projection

My aim is to take a vector v in 3D space, project it onto a provided plane P with normal N, but do so along a direction vector D.

That is, I would like to obtain an oblique (non-orthogonal) projection of of a point onto a plane.

I've reviewed [this question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4360/how-to-project-a-3D-point-onto-a-plane-along-another-axis-vector) but using the formula with some simple example values results in a poor output with denominator of 0, I feel as I'm having a conceptual mishap.

The image below describes the problem.
[image: Diagram in 3D]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a plane defined by a point **p** and a normal vector **n**, a point **v** and a vector **D**, and you want to find a point **w** in the plane, such that **w** = **v** + k**D**, for some number k. Is that right?

Comment: The yellow plane P is actually defined by the light green points, and a normal vector n.  The rest I believe is correct - I have a pink point v which I want to project onto that plane, and find its resultant point w in the plane.  However, it is not orthogonal projection but a projection in direction of the x-axis [1,0,0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**n•p** = **n•w** (siince **p** and **w** are both in the plane)
= **n•**(**v** + k**D**)
= **n•v** + k**n•D**
k**n•D** = **n•**(**p** - **v**)
k = **n•**(**p** - **v**) / (**n•D**)
**w** = **v** + (**n•**(**p** - **v**) / (**n•D**))**D**

Comment: So this uses the fact that the bottom two points (pink) are already on the plane, correct? I should have clarified that this will not always be the case, where a point is on the plane. Could a general formula apply when the point p is not on the inclined plane?

Comment: @cz_robot: A plane can be defined by a normal vector and *one* point in the plane. I assumed you were defining it that way, and named that point "p". If you don't have such a point, then how do you define the plane?

Comment: Ok now I see, apologies.  Correct, we have a plane defined by normal n and a point p (one of the light green dots) which is obviously sitting on said plane. My concern is the projection of a point v (one of the pink dots), onto that plane. But in the direction of the x-axis (i.e, not an orthogonal projection)

Comment: @cz_robot: Yes, that's what I addressed in my Answer.